# Exception Thrown When Generating Migration for JSONB Column with Npgsql and EF Core

Tags: npgsql, ef-core-3.1

This exception is thrown when I try to generate a migration with Npgsql and EF Core.

```
The property 'MyClass.MyProperty' is of type 'IDictionary<string, object>' which is not supported by current database provider. Either change the property CLR type or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
```

Just for debugging purposes, I set the following `HasConversion` code (using `System.Text.Json`) which got rid of the exception.

```
eb.Property(a => a.MyProperty).HasConversion(
  b => JsonSerializer.Serialize(x, new JsonSerializerOptions()),
  b => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IDictionary<string, object>>(x, new JsonSerializerOptions())
).HasColumnType("jsonb");
```

I could replace the two faux conversion functions with Newtonsoft JSON functions, but it doesn't seem like the best solution.  Does Npgsql EF Core have a built in function for EF Core's `.HasConversion` function?

```
class MyClass {
  public Dictionary<string, object> MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you specified that MyProperty should be mapped to a `jsonb` column as per [the docs](http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html?tabs=data-annotations%2Cpoco)?

Comment: @ShayRojansky i have same error with array of object. But OP has HasColumnType("jsonb") in the middle.